# Facing issue after importing project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am downloading the source code, which is in zip form. When I unzip the folder using Peazip and import it into eclipse, I don't find any contents in the project. Please provide solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You have to map the source folder to your project. 
Right click on your project and click project. Add link to source folder.
Now you can see the source code of your project.